# How to add map with marker to adapter item in android?

Tags: android, android-mapview

I have added `mapview` in the layout. How to set map marker dynamically based on items in the list?

```
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
                xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/map"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                map:cameraZoom="15"
                map:liteMode="false"
                map:mapType="normal" />
```

Comment: list is static or coming in to the response ??

Comment: dynamic response

Comment: refer this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36004099/add-multiple-markers-on-google-map-from-json-response

Comment: each item should have separate map with marker in adapter items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `onBindViewHolder` for your map view Implement `OnMapReadyCallback` and override `onMapReady()`.

Something like this:

```
holder.mMapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback()
{
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        holder.mMapView = googleMap;

        if (holder.mMapView != null) {
            holder.mMapView.addMarker(...);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using the Lat and Lng for desired position to put marker.

```
fun addMarker(latLng: LatLng) {

val options = MarkerOptions().position(latLng)
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.icon))

map.addMarker(options)
}
```

Comment: each item should have separate map in adapter items. you have mentioned for single map